# Syntax explanation for intersections of perpendicular lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

Specifying coordinates of intersection is quite neat with `|-` (https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.3).

`\node at (A |- B) {};` resolves in (A.x, B.y), while
`\node at (A -| B) {};` resolves in (A.y, B.x).

I thought `-|` would take the horizontal (x-coordinate) from the left argument and the vertical (y-coordinate) from the right argument. But it is in fact the other way round.

Is there an intuitive explanation for this syntax?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don’t know whether this was the original idea, but I remember this with viewing the horizontal or vertical stroke as tick on a vertical or horizontal scale.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as 'aligning to' rather than 'taking from'. `(A |- B)` picks a point which is aligned vertically with `A` and horizontally with `B`, whereas `(A -| B)` is aligned horizontally with `A` and vertically with `B`. To get horizontal alignment, you align with the `y` coordinate; to get vertical alignment, you align with the `x`.

Comment: Maybe also mention the path construction `(A) |- (B)` that works in the same way and is more intuitively read.

Answer (score 0):

The constructs `-|` or `|-` literately mean intersections of two invisible **infinite** lines tangent to each other, crossing two specified points. I would just denote them as *lines*. The component  `|` corresponds to a vertical line whereas component `-` corresponds to a horizontal line. The order matters and here are two examples.

Consider a point `A` and a point `B`, the latter to be lower and at the right-hand side of `A`. `(A |- B)` would first take a vertical line that crosses point `A` and then a horizontal line that crosses point `B` and return the intersection. That intersection would be below `A` and to the left of `B`. On the other hand, `(A -| B)` would first take a horizontal line crossing `A`, then vertical line crossing `B` and return the intersection, which in turn would be to the right from `A` and above `B`.

Hope this helps.